# Why do we have interfaces and initialstates in React and typescript for Redux tool kit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am learning how to use typescript with react and I am new to all those technologies.

In the example below why do we write the codes like that; I am studying from a code base and the Redux tool kit has been used and the logic is written in this way as below:
why do we have interfaces and initial states separately? I know that I am missing a lot of basic. Thank you for your help.

```
export interface ProjectState {
  projectId: number | undefined;
  project: Project | undefined;
  projectInfo: ProjectInfo | undefined;
  fields: Array<Field> | undefined;

const initialState: ProjectState = {
  projectId: undefined,
  project: undefined,
  projectInfo: undefined,
  fields: undefined,
```

Answer (score 0):

first is good to recall the basics, an interface in typescript is like a contract within an object and the shape it should implement. So another thing is you can't create an instance of an interface, you will never see something like this.

```
export interface ProjectState {
 ...
}

const project = new ProjectState;
```

This is why you are watching the initial state and the interface separately.
The principal reason why the people prefer to create an interface insted of using ***type***, is to export it and re-use the same contract in others part of the application.

Keep in you learning process, you are doing great!

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate your help. That makes sense now.